# brown and white sugar is made of sugar cane or are made of sugar cane?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement, compounds

Which sentence is correct:

> White and brown sugar **is** made of sugar cane?

or

> White and brown sugar **are** made of sugar cane?

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about a mixture of white and brown sugar (speckled sugar), that would be a single product, so you would use "is".  If you are referring to white and brown sugar as two different products, that would be plural so you would use "are".